# finding limits as function approaches zero

Tags: limits, exponential-function

> Set $n=1+\epsilon$ and let $\epsilon$ tend to zero.
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> c_1 &= \frac1{2\pi} \left[\frac{e^{i\pi (1+\epsilon)}-e^{-i\pi(1+\epsilon)}}{(1+\epsilon)^2-1}\right]\\
> &= \frac1{2\pi} \left[\frac{-e^{i\pi\epsilon}+e^{-i\pi\epsilon}}{(1+\epsilon)^2-1}\right]\\
> &\approx \frac1{2\pi} \left[\frac{-1-i\pi\epsilon+1-i\pi\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon-1}\right]\\
> &\approx \frac1{2\pi} \left[\frac{-2i\pi\epsilon}{2\epsilon}\right]\\
> &\approx \frac{-i}2 \\
> &\approx \frac1{2i}
> \end{align}
> $$

[image: function to be explained]

Can someone please explain this to me, I get the first 2 steps but get confused on what happens to the numerator in the 3rd step. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=1+\frac x{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots$$

For $x\to0,$  $$e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$$